# How to remove the self-reference of the ToC in Latex book class

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I want to remove the self-reference of the ToC in Latex book class as in the picture below

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. You clearly are using `hyperref` package and that is not reflected in any way in your question.

Answer (score 14):

The class `book` does not include starred chapters into the table of contents. The `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures` use a starred chapter internally, therefore I guess that you are using package [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) that includes both `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures` in the table of contents. The first can be disabled by option `nottoc`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Class `CUEDthesis`

The class contains:

```
\usepackage{tocbibind}
```

Thus my guess is quite correct. ☺

Since the option `nottoc` cannot be given after loading the class (except using an internal `\@dotoctocfalse`), the option can be given before:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{nottoc}{tocbibind}
\documentclass{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
```

Comment: It doestn't work. I use the standard Cambridge University PhD/MPhil thesis latex template here http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.zip

Comment: @Justlife Your question has stated class `book`. That's one of the reasons people request a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: It works well for me. Heiko Oberdiek, I love your solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get a `Contents` line in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents%
    \chapter{First}
    \lipsum%
    \chapter{Second}
    \lipsum%
\end{document}
```

Do you have a line that is something like

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
```

near to `\tableofcontents`? The `\addcontentsline` will add an entry to `toc` at the the `chapter` level called `Contents`.

Comment: Dear Chris, I use the standard Cambridge University PhD/MPhil thesis latex template here http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/